# Problems with efficient solution except for a small fraction of inputs

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, computability, undecidability

> The halting problem for Turing machines is perhaps the canonical undecidable
>   set. Nevertheless, we prove that there is an algorithm deciding almost
>   all instances of it. The halting problem is therefore among the growing collection
>   of those exhibiting the “black hole” phenomenon of complexity theory,
>   by which the difficulty of an unfeasible or undecidable problem is confined
>   to a very small region, a black hole, outside of which the problem is easy.
>
> [Joel David Hamkins and Alexei Miasnikov, "[The halting problem is decidable on a set of asymptotic probability one](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504351)", 2005]

Can anyone provide references to other “black holes” in complexity theory, or another place where this or related concepts are discussed?

Comment: Joel regularly visits MathOverflow, you can ask the question here to get an answer from him. IIRC there was a question about the result there.

Comment: See also [HeurP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:H#heurp).

Comment: Perhaps another example is Graph Isomorphism (which is an NP-intermediate problem).
On "real instances" it is very easy (trivial for random instances?) and for many graph classes there is a polynomial time algorithm. The "black hole" seems so tight that it is not so easy to generate hard instances and nauty, one of the most efficient tool to *solve* it, is often used to *generate* (hard) instances. But perhaps, the "black hole" will vanish and will leave the poor GI in P :-D

Comment: @Marzio, non-real world examples are not usually a small fraction of all instances and is different from what they are referring to in the paper.

Comment: HeurP sounds like it assumes a probability distribution on instances, but I think a nice different formalization of the phenomenon would be this: The language $A$ is hard for some class, but there exists a promise problem $A' = (A'_y,A'_n)$ that is in some easier class with $A'_y$ "asmyptotically dense" in $A$ and $A'_n$ "asymptotically dense" in $\bar{A}$, where asmyptotically is as the size of the strings in the languages goes to infinity.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is what you're looking, but the phase transition in random SAT is an example. Let $\rho$ be the ratio of number of clauses to number of variables. Then a random SAT instance with parameter $\rho$ is very likely to be satisfiable if $\rho$ is less than a fixed constant (near 4.2) and is very likely to be unsatisfiable if $\rho$ is a little bit more than this constant. The "black hole" is the phase transition.

Comment: Similar to this, Ham Cycle can be shown to be polytime solvable on a random graph (according to some reasonable random generation process), yet it is NP-hard just because of very specially-constructed examples. There are many other examples along this line.

Answer (score 5):

Like the Halting problem, *Post's Correspondence Problem* is undecidable in general. Ling Zhao's Master's thesis describes a large set of solvable instances of the PCP problem, including some "hard" instances. But I don't know if the size/density/measure of his set of solvable instances is on par with the Halting Problem result you cite.

http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~games/PCP/paper/CG2002.pdf